# CONCAT and UPDATE in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to execute this query:

If I get anything in POST['domain'] then I want to update the md_user field for each user in the Table.

> UPDATE `NECOFFICE_users` SET `md_user` = md5(concat(ext,'@192.168.50.1')) WHERE `site_key` = 'EB22-0000'

This query runs perfectly fine in **PHPMYADMIN**

And My Active Record Code is :

```
$user_table = $this->session->userdata('user_table');
$string_md = $this->input->post('domain');


$this->db->set("md_user",md5("CONCAT('ext',@$string_md)"));
$this->db->where('site_key', $site_session);
$this->db->update($user_table);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Now this what should be my code to perform the above query in codeigniter ?

Comment: Try with `$pass=md5("CONCAT('ext','@'.$string_md)");$this->db->set("md_user",$pass);
`

Comment: it inserts same record for all users @Saty

Comment: Why its inserting?? I don't understand it

Comment: I mean it updates all records with same record @Saty

Comment: all user have a field called md_user so i set the same md_user for all users

Comment: check what `$pass print ` `echo $pass=md5("CONCAT('ext','@'.$string_md)");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110227/discussion-between-rajan-and-saty).

Comment: I Dont Understand, I have domain here in post but i dont have the ext of all users, So how will this work $pass=md5("CONCAT('ext','@'.$string_md)");

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the PHP MD5 function, instead of MySQL's:

```
$this->db->set("md_user",array("md5(CONCAT('ext',@{$string_md}))"), FALSE);
```

Try that, looks like it should work.

Edit:

After looking up CI's set method, you might be better just building it up without using MySQL's functions:

> $this->db->set("md_user",md5('ext@' . $string_md));

Comment: it genrates this query :UPDATE `NECOFFICE_users` SET `md_user` = 'md5(CONCAT(\'ext\',@192.168.50.150))' WHERE `site_key` = 'EB22-0000'

Comment: so in database this is updated in md_5: md5(CONCAT('ext',@192.168.50.150))

Comment: Haha of course. Hang on, you need SQL Expression.. finding out how to do that in CI

Comment: Yeah Please Thank you

Comment: Updated - try that? I don't have any CI projects setup so hard to test.

Comment: Now i get this error UPDATE `NECOFFICE_users` SET `md_user` = Array WHERE `site_key` = 'EB22-0000'

Comment: I tried this but it updates all the records i guess i have to update it like this :`$this->db->query("UPDATE `$user_table` SET `md_user` = md5(concat(ext,'$domain_md')) WHERE `site_key` = '$site_session'");`

Comment: i think CI's Active records dont support this query so wil have to execute it in native way